# iOS video streaming and storing this video on the device

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming

So far I know how to stream a video and how to download it and afterwards stream it, but here's the tricky bit: streaming it once, storing it on the device and in the future play it from the device. how it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you know how to stream it and download it you have solved 60% of your problem.

I would store URL and stream together with file name on the device, then when user taps on video I would check if I already have file for that URL and start playing it directly if I have, otherwise start streaming it from URL.